# SAS: Looping through Logistic Regression Score table, calculating profit with cut-off, and output cut-off along with profit into seperate table

Tags: loops, macros, sas, maximum-profit-problem

So to begin, I have completed a binary logistic regression model, and output several tables. I have a 'scored' data set that contains the actual default of a customer (GOODBAD) which is binary. I then have a predicted probability of default (p_1) that ranges from 0 to 1. I then must decide a cut-off value, generate a new variable that is a predicted-default that is now binary.

What I'm attempting to do is loop through potential cut-off values (lets say from .1 to .5 by a step of .1), and then calculate 'profit' from each of these 5 steps. I then want both the cut-off value and the 'profit' value in a separate data set to generate a graph of this relationship so that I may find my maximal profit.

Below is the code I currently have for generating a specific cut-off and it's associated profit. (the proc report shouldn't change at all, as these are pre-determined values for accounts/situations)

```
%MACRO PROFIT;

%DO I=1 %TO 5;

DATA TEST&i;
SET TRANS.SCORE;
IF P_1 >= .&i THEN preds = 1;
ELSE preds = 0;
RUN;

Data probs&i;
format outcometype $6.;
Set TEST&i (keep=preds goodbad crelim);
crelim2 = crelim/2;
if (preds=1 and goodbad=0) then do;
 outcometype="error2";
 profit =0;
end;
else if (preds=0 and goodbad=1) then do;
 outcometype ="error1";
 profit =-crelim2;
end;
else if (preds=1 and goodbad=1) then do;
 outcometype="valid1";
 profit=0;
end;
else do;
 outcometype="valid2";
 profit=250;
end;
run;

PROC REPORT DATA= probs&i nowd out=table&i;
COLUMN outcometype pct n profit pper1000;
DEFINE outcometype /group width = 8 ;
DEFINE profit /format=dollar15.2;
define pper1000 / computed format=dollar15.2;
/*get the overall number of obs*/
compute before;
overall=n;
endcomp;
compute pper1000;
pper1000 = (profit.sum/n)*1000;
endcomp;
compute before outcometype;
totaln=n;
endcomp;
compute pct;
pct = (totaln/overall);
if _break_ = '_RBREAK_' then pct= (overall/overall);
endcomp;
rbreak after/summarize dol;
RUN;
quit;

Data out;
set table&i;
CALL symput('profitAT', PUT(pper1000));
run;

Data new;
CutOFF = .&i;
profit = &profitAT;
run;

%END;

*proc print data = new; Run;

%MEND PROFIT;
%PROFIT;
```

The problem I'm having and I cannot seem to resolve is that I am over-writing the previous value with the most current value of both i and pper100 (or the macro variable profitAT).

I dont know how to force this to be seen as observations, if I should be looping through my macro variables, if, since I am placing them in the data step, I should have a separate loop that will check *N* and then write the observations as *N* increases, or yet further if there's an alternative I have yet to discover.

Comment: Please indent for better readability within `data` and `proc` steps as well as `%do` and `%macro` blocks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean with "over-writing the previous value"?  Are you talking about the fact that at the end of the  loop you generating two datasets with constant names? or do you mean the macro variable that the call symput statement is generating which also does not have a dynamically generated name?

Comment: Also is there a reason that you seem to be trying to save the data from your PROC REPORT step?  Is the purpose to generate the report? or to generate the data?  If the later then why not use data step or other normal method to generate the PPER1000 variable instead of using a reporting proc?

Comment: The report is generating the output I want, but I'm only able to store the final iteration of the macro.

To clarify, I've run this code without using a macro, and i can get the information I desire, but I want to automate.

 i.e the report gives a profit of ($5,400, $5,600, $5,700, $5,900, $5,600) for i=1,...,5 but my only output in the new data set is $5,600. the macro appears to be overwriting the value in the data step because it's not writing the values as each of 1,...5 observations but rather it's re-writing the previous value in the data set with the current macro variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore the logic that is generating the dataset TABLE&i and the variable PPER1000 and concentrate on the looping aspects.
You can use PROC APPEND as a method to aggregate values in your loop.

```
%macro profit ;
%if %sysfunc(exist(new)) %then %do;
* Remove existing NEW dataset on first pass;
proc delete data=new;
run;
%end;

%do i=1 %to 5;
* ... generate TABLE&i ... ;

* Get value of PPER1000 from last observation of TABLE&i ;
data add;
  set table&i end=eof ;
  if eof;
  cutoff = .&i;
  profit = pper1000;
  keep cutoff profit;
run;
* Accumulate results in NEW dataset. ;
proc append base=new data=add force ;
run;

%end;
proc print data = new; run;
%mend profit ;
%profit;
```